# How to solve this error in using TypeError: Expected int32, got <tf.Variable 'lstm_1_W_i:0' in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I am training a Vanilla RNN in Keras, using LSTM cells. 
This is the shape of my training data. Basically 600 samples, each sample is a 2500 length vector with 100 features.

`>>> training_data.shape
(600, 2500, 100)`

Here is the start of my model definition in Keras.

```
rnn_inputs = Input(shape=(2500, 100), dtype='int32')
simple_rnn = LSTM(3, return_sequences=True,activation='relu')(rnn_inputs)
```

The first 'rnn_inputs' runs fine, but the second line, 'simple_rnn' raises this error:

```
TypeError: Expected int32, got <tf.Variable 'lstm_1_W_i:0' shape=(100, 3) dtype=float32_ref> of type 'Variable' instead.
```

The version of Keras I am using is 1.0.7 and tensorflow version is 1.5.0. I think it has something to do with the version of these libraries though, I updated and tried it and it doesn't work.

Trace

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-fe4504deb980> in <module>()
      2 rnn_inputs = Input(shape=(2500, 100), dtype='float64')
      3 print(rnn_inputs.dtype)
----> 4 simple_rnn = LSTM(3, return_sequences=True,activation='relu')(rnn_inputs)
      5 #output = TimeDistributed(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))(simple_rnn)
      6 #model = Model(inputs=rnn_inputs, outputs=output)

~/miniconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py in __call__(self, x, mask)
    482                                     '`layer.build(batch_input_shape)`')
    483             if len(input_shapes) == 1:
--> 484                 self.build(input_shapes[0])
    485             else:
    486                 self.build(input_shapes)

~/miniconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/layers/recurrent.py in build(self, input_shape)
    729                                       self.W_o, self.U_o, self.b_o]
    730 
--> 731             self.W = K.concatenate([self.W_i, self.W_f, self.W_c, self.W_o])
    732             self.U = K.concatenate([self.U_i, self.U_f, self.U_c, self.U_o])
    733             self.b = K.concatenate([self.b_i, self.b_f, self.b_c, self.b_o])

~/miniconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in concatenate(tensors, axis)
    667         else:
    668             axis = 0
--> 669     return tf.concat(axis, tensors)
    670 
    671 

~/miniconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py in concat(values, axis, name)
   1125       ops.convert_to_tensor(
   1126           axis, name="concat_dim",
-> 1127           dtype=dtypes.int32).get_shape().assert_is_compatible_with(
   1128               tensor_shape.scalar())
   1129       return identity(values[0], name=scope)

~/miniconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in convert_to_tensor(value, dtype, name, preferred_dtype)
    930       name=name,
    931       preferred_dtype=preferred_dtype,
--> 932       as_ref=False)
    933 
    934 

~/miniconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in internal_convert_to_tensor(value, dtype, name, as_ref, preferred_dtype, ctx)
   1020 
   1021     if ret is None:
-> 1022       ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
   1023 
   1024     if ret is NotImplemented:

~/miniconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in _constant_tensor_conversion_function(v, dtype, name, as_ref)
    231                                          as_ref=False):
    232   _ = as_ref
--> 233   return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
    234 
    235 

~/miniconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in constant(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape)
    210   tensor_value.tensor.CopyFrom(
    211       tensor_util.make_tensor_proto(
--> 212           value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape))
    213   dtype_value = attr_value_pb2.AttrValue(type=tensor_value.tensor.dtype)
    214   const_tensor = g.create_op(

~/miniconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py in make_tensor_proto(values, dtype, shape, verify_shape)
    411       nparray = np.empty(shape, dtype=np_dt)
    412     else:
--> 413       _AssertCompatible(values, dtype)
    414       nparray = np.array(values, dtype=np_dt)
    415       # check to them.

~/miniconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py in _AssertCompatible(values, dtype)
    326     else:
    327       raise TypeError("Expected %s, got %s of type '%s' instead." %
--> 328                       (dtype.name, repr(mismatch), type(mismatch).__name__))
    329 
    330 

TypeError: Expected int32, got <tf.Variable 'lstm_7_W_i:0' shape=(100, 3) dtype=float32_ref> of type 'Variable' instead.
```

Any clue on what the issue is?

Comment: Change `int32` to `float32` runs fine for me.

Comment: @gongzhitaao Just tried that, it didn't work. I get the same error `TypeError: Expected int32, got <tf.Variable 'lstm_5_W_i:0' shape=(100, 3) dtype=float32_ref> of type 'Variable' instead.`

Comment: You sure this line causes the problem?  I copy-paste those two lines and it runs. `tf v1.7`

Comment: @gongzhitaao Yeah, what version of Keras and tensorflow are you using? The original dtype of the data is float64, but changing everything to float64 doesn't solve it either. To avoid this issue, I wrote the data to a pickle and used a different Keras library, the newer one.

Comment: You should include the complete backtrace, not just the exception message.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Sure. See updated question.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you are specifying dtype in the Input layer?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Originally, I did not specify the dtype but I get the same error with or without it.